# how to initialize(pass arguments) fragments for action bar tabs?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I followed http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

It uses the following code to add Tab.

```
Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.artist)
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<ArtistFragment>(
                    this, "artist", ArtistFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

I want to supply argument to the fragment's constructor or call myInit(myVariableList) method on the fragment instance before showing the tab for the first time.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `tab.setTag()` to link an arbitrary object to the tab.  If you can put `myVariableList` into a `Bundle`, you can achieve a simple solution by doing the following --

```
Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.artist)
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<ArtistFragment>(
                    this, "artist", ArtistFragment.class));
    tab.setTag(myVariableBundle);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

Then, in your `onTabSelected` callback, send the `Bundle` when you instantiate your fragment --

```
mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), (Bundle) tab.getTag());
```

You should then be able to access your `Bundle` during the fragment lifecycle using `getArguments()`

Comment: wow nice. Is there a way to retrieve a tab by (class/tag/whatever) and call a method on it as well?

Comment: In what context do you want to retrieve the tab?  It is already available from the creation context (as the variable `tab`) and in the `onTabSelected` method as the parameter `tab`.

Comment: i'll ask separate question. Thanks!